# How to troubleshoot failed requests to Azure web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure

I have a ASP .NET Core MVC web service hosted in Azure to which I would like to POST data.  I am able to post from Postman so I know the service is working and the required format of the request.  I have another client sending what I believe to be the same post request but somewhere the request is failing.  I would like to confirm the requests are reaching the service and if so see exactly what the request looks like when it gets there so I can compare to the working version.  I have enabled web logs on the service but what info I can find as a result does not provide detail of the failed request.  I also downloaded logs via the Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio but again I cannot see the content of the request to troubleshoot. I'm sure I'm not utilizing the logging fully but I'm not familiar enough with Azure web services to know what I'm missing and am having trouble finding guidance on the web.  Perhaps it is not possible to capture the failed post data for security reasons?  If so then presumably I need to hook up a debugger and see if I can step through the processing of the request.

What would be the most effective way to troubleshoot failed web service requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found an excellent reference on troubleshooting Azure Web Services at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio.  Using the information and tools covered there I was able to resolve my problem which ultimately proved to be a problem sending the request. Watching the web server logs it became clear the client's request was never reaching the server.